# Create patterned polygon fill in ArcMap with random sized dots?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, random, fill

I would like to create a polygon fill with a pattern of dots that are randomly sized (within a range). If this is possible in ArcMap 10.4 desktop, how should I go about this?

Comment: Not really without writing a new renderer in ArcObjects.. you can approximate this by creating multiple marker fill layers in a symbol with different dot sizes within your range.

Comment: this worked great.

Answer (score 1):

There is no renderer that could do this direct but as a workaround:

1. Use the [Create Random Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm) tool to create point features in random locations (if they need to randomly located too)
2. Use the Python Parser of the Field Calculator to create random values in a field on those points that you might name RandomSize
3. Symbolize your points using the RandomSize field to set their size